# Combination VS Permutation using Recursion

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, depth-first-search

I'm practicing algorithm questions recently. I found two very similar questions and put them together for learning purposes.

> Question 1: Have all the k combinations from n - e.g. n=4 and k=3 then we return {[1,2,3],[1,3,4],[2,3,4],[1,2,4]}

Answer:

```
public static List<List<Integer>> combine(int n, int k) {
    List<List<Integer>> res = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
    if(k > n || n <= 0) {
        return res;
    }
    ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    helper(res, n, k, 1, a);
    return res;
}

private static void helper(List<List<Integer>> res, int n, int k, int start, ArrayList<Integer> a) {
    if(a.size() == k){
        res.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(a));
        return;
    }

    for(int i=start; i<=n; i++) {
        a.add(i);
        helper(res, n, k, i+1, a);
        a.remove(a.size()-1);
    }
}
```

> Question 2: Have all the permutations of an array: {1,2,3} -> {123},{132},{213},{231},{321},{312}.

Answer:

```
public static List<List<Integer>> permute(int[] num) {
    List<List<Integer>> rst = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
    if (num == null || num.length == 0) {
        return rst; 
    }

    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    helper(rst, list, num);
    return rst;
}

public static void helper(List<List<Integer>> rst, ArrayList<Integer> list, int[] num){
    if(list.size() == num.length) {
        rst.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(list));
        return;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i<num.length; i++) {
        if(list.contains(num[i])){
            continue;
        }
        list.add(num[i]);
        helper(rst, list, num);
        list.remove(list.size() - 1);
    }
}
```

For question 2, we start from index 0; for question 1, why does the for loop index need to be started at `start`, and why do we need pass a `start` parameter to helper method?

Comment: By the way, permute(n) = combine(n, n), so there's no need for two separate implementations

Comment: Nope, they are different. Combine(3,3) will give he result of (1,2,3) only ....

Comment: @NiklasB. Yeah, not being an english speaker by birth or education, I had the same initial thought, so I looked it up and found this good explanation of [Combination vs. Permutation](https://www.mathsisfun.com/combinatorics/combinations-permutations.html)

Comment: @catlovespurple, what does tag dfs mean?

Comment: @AntonDanilov depth first search...

Comment: @NiklasB. Thanks for the editing, very helpful...

Comment: @NiklasB. haha my bad .... typo...

Answer (score 0):

Don't be surprised being looking at the Prolog code. I decided this will be useful to look at the problem from different view points.

Combination is an **arbitrary subset** of the set containing given number of elements. The order of elements is irrelevant.

```
comb(0,_,[]).
comb(N,[X|T],[X|Comb]):-N>0,N1 is N-1,comb(N1,T,Comb).
comb(N,[_|T],Comb):-N>0,comb(N,T,Comb).
```

Permutation of the list *L* is a list containing **all elements** of list *L* in some order.

```
perm(List,[H|Perm]):-select(H,List,Rest),perm(Rest,Perm).
perm([],[]).

select(X,[X|T],T).
select(X,[H|T],[H|NT]):-select(X,T,NT).
```

So my answer is:

We need the start index in *combination* case to specify subset size.